# No recipes available (meta-wandboard-ap)

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I have already built an image for wandboard using [fsl-community-bsp-platform](https://github.com/Freescale/fsl-community-bsp-platform) manifest and dunfell branch. I use bitbake core-image-minimal to make the build.

The idea is that I want to turn Wandboard into a wireless access point using [meta-wandboard-ap](https://github.com/johnweber/meta-wandboard-ap). I followed all the instructions and add the layer to BBLAYERS in build/conf/bblayers.conf.

When I attempt to run the bitbake command to create the image, I get the following error message:

```
sami@sami-deepevent:~/fsl-community-bsp-dunfell/wandboard$ bitbake core-image-minimal
WARNING: Layer wandboard-ap should set LAYERSERIES_COMPAT_wandboard-ap in its conf/layer.conf file to list the core layer names it is compatible with.
WARNING: Layer wandboard-ap should set LAYERSERIES_COMPAT_wandboard-ap in its conf/layer.conf file to list the core layer names it is compatible with.
Loading cache: 100% |##########################################################| Time: 0:00:00
Loaded 3269 entries from dependency cache.
Parsing recipes: 100% |########################################################| Time: 0:00:00
Parsing of 2177 .bb files complete (2176 cached, 1 parsed). 3269 targets, 267 skipped, 0 masked, 0 errors.
ERROR: No recipes available for:
  /home/sami/fsl-community-bsp-dunfell/sources/meta-wandboard-ap/recipes-kernel/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_git.bbappend

Summary: There were 2 WARNING messages shown.
Summary: There was 1 ERROR message shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

That's the content of the linux-firmware_git.bbappend file:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"

SRC_URI_append = " \
  file://fw_bcm4329_apsta.bin \
  file://fw_bcm4330_apsta_bg.bin \
"
do_install_append () {
    install -m 644 ${WORKDIR}/fw_bcm4329_apsta.bin ${D}/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac4329-ap-sdio.bin
    install -m 644 ${WORKDIR}/fw_bcm4330_apsta_bg.bin ${D}/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac4330-ap-sdio.bin
}

FILES_${PN}-bcm4329 += " \
  /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac4329-ap-sdio.bin \
"

FILES_${PN}-bcm4330 += " \
  /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac4330-ap-sdio.bin \
"

ALTERNATIVE_TARGET_linux-firmware-bcm4329[brcmfmac4329-sdio.bin] = "${BRCM_FWDIR}/brcmfmac4329-ap-sdio.bin"
ALTERNATIVE_PRIORITY_linux-firmware-bcm4329[brcmfmac4329-sdio.bin] = "90"

ALTERNATIVE_TARGET_linux-firmware-bcm4330[brcmfmac4330-sdio.bin] = "${BRCM_FWDIR}/brcmfmac4330-ap-sdio.bin"
ALTERNATIVE_PRIORITY_linux-firmware-bcm4329[brcmfmac4330-sdio.bin] = "90"
```

What could be the reason for this error? How to make it find the files and recipes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Yocto, when creating a `.bbappend` file, the original `.bb` file must exist in one of the layers in `bblayers.conf`.

The problem is that Yocto parsing stage will try to append the content of `linux-firmware_git.bbappend` to `linux-firmware_git.bb`.

That failed, which means that you have no `linux-firmware_git.bb` recipe.

But the `linux-firmware` recipe exists in `meta` layer of poky. You can check in this [link](http://cgit.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/tree/meta/recipes-kernel/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_20211027.bb?h=dunfell).

The recipe exists in `dunfell` under version: `linux-firmware_20211027.bb`

So, just change `linux-firmware_git.bbappend` to:

```
linux_firmware_%.bbappend
```

with that, it will match the highest version available for `linux-firmware`.

Also, make sure `meta` is present in your `bblayers.conf`.

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried this but now it shows a ParseError like the following: "ERROR: ParseError at /home/sami/fsl-community-bsp-dunfell/sources/meta-fsl-arm/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-imx_4.1.15.bb:9: Could not include required file recipes-kernel/linux/linux-dtb.inc" I checked and linux-dtb.inc is not there

Comment: The `linux-dtb.inc` file was used in poky/meta but it has been removed, so remove that line from `linux-imx_4.1.15.bb`

Comment: If my solution is correct for your question please accept it as a correct answer, because your new error is not related the posted question.